# gfortran cannot match MacOS Ventura version

Tags: macos, version-control, fortran, gfortran

The new MacOS Ventura seems to have broken gfortran MacOS version control. To reproduce my error you only have to do

```
 gfortran --version
```

And the output is

```
gfortran: warning: could not understand version ‘13.00.00’
GNU Fortran (GCC) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

This in itself is just a warning so it might not be a big deal but it breaks "./configure" scripts that require some MacOS versions, e.g. if you try to compile [LoopTools](https://feynarts.de/looptools/) you get the following error (in the log file)

```
arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-gfortran: warning: could not understand version '13.00.00'
ld: -rpath can only be used when targeting Mac OS X 10.5 or later
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Since the version cannot be properly read it cannot be compared.

Is there some sort of work around this bug?

Comment: How did you install gfortran? Not too surprising that a 2021 gfortran version does not recognise the just released macOS Ventura. You should try updating gfortran to the latest available version first.

Comment: I installed it from conda today. Removed it and installed with `brew install gcc`. Apparently conda has an earlier version. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had installed gfortran through conda but aparantly the version is from last year.

I solved it by removing it from conda (had to remove conda entirely due to linking issues) and installed it with brew : `brew install gcc`.

Comment: My edit of this answer has been rejected, but still I think the answer is ambiguous. *"I solved it by removing **it** from conda..."*: the second "it" semantically refers to "gfortran". *"and installed **it** with brew"*: again this "it" semantically refers to "gfortran". So the `brew install conda` command is not consistent.

Comment: @PierU Yes, you are correct.